# Is it possible to un-eject a kindle via CLI?

Tags: command-line, usb, mount, kindle

When I connect my kindle, it "appears" as `/dev/sdb` and its main partition as `/dev/sdb1`. I can then mount the kindle and move files to it.

Afterwards, to return to reading, I need to do an `umount /dev/sdb1` followed by an `eject /dev/sdb`. The device `/dev/sdb1` disappears.

My question is: can I make `/dev/sdb1` reappear via the CLI, without reconnecting the device physically?

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be one quick `man eject` away:

```
eject -t /dev/sdb
```

```
-t   With this option the drive is given a CD-ROM tray close command.
     Not all devices support this command.
```